# MySQL one to many data relationship with added complications

Tags: mysql

I have a database in which there are multiple posts. Each post can be associated with one or more location. Each location is then associated with one country.

This is handled through four tables:

- post (with the `id` and `post_title`)
- postlocation (with the fields `post_id` and `location_id` - to allow a one to many relationship)
- location (with the fields `id`, `location_title` and `country_id`)
- country (with the `fields`, `id` and `country_title`)

I want to perform a simple, effective select to retrieve a list of posts and each one's associated locations and each of those locations' country.

I'm at a loss as to how to best achieve this, and any help would be most welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT post.*, location.*, country.*
FROM post
LEFT JOIN postlocation ON post.id = postlocation.post_id
LEFT JOIN location ON postlocation.location_id = location.id
LEFT JOIN country ON location.country_id = country.id
```

Here's an explanation of how LEFT JOIN works: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx

> The MySQL LEFT JOIN clause works like this: when a row from the left
>   table matches a row from the right table based on join_condition, the
>   row’s content are selected as an output row. When row in the left
>   table has no match it is still selected for output, but combined with
>   a “fake” row from the right table that contains NULL in all columns.
>   In short, the MySQL LEFT JOIN clause allows you to select all rows
>   from the left table even there is no match for them in the right
>   table.

When you have multiple LEFT JOINs, then in each case it uses the cumulative results so far as the "left" table and the table your are joining on as the "right" table.

So the query above will return one row for every post/location/country. Note that this means there will be potentially several rows with the same `post.*` data (one for each `postlocation` associated with taht post).

And if a post has no postlocations associated with it, that post will still show up in the results (but with null rows for `location.*` and `country.*`). Similarly, if a location has no country associated it with it, the post/location rows will still show up in the output (but with null rows for `country.*`). This is the advantage of LEFT JOIN -- you always get all the rows from the table on the "left".

Comment: That is perfect - Exactly what I was after. Thank you so much for your help.